# Why is git-log with perl regex negative lookbehind causing a fatal error?

Tags: regex, git, pcre, git-log

Either I cannot get git-log's regexp grep functionality to search using perl based regexp (pcre) or I can but it is not working with negative lookbehind.

```
git log -p -P -G'(?<!-)title'
```

results in output

```
fatal: invalid regex: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

However, pcre support and negative lookbehind seems to be working, if git-grep is any indicator.
E.g. `git grep -P '(?<!-)title'` returns expected results.

git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-P` doesn't influence `-G`. You can verify it by replacing `-P` with `-F` (or `--fixed-string`): you'll still get the same error, even if there's no look-around at all in fixed strings.

The documentation of `-P` says

> Consider the limiting patterns to be Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Note the word "patterns". Indeed, the `--grep` options mentions it:

> --grep=<pattern>

On the other hand, `-G` doesn't:

> -G<regex>

Comment: `--grep` only works on the commit message, not the diff @EricLavault